# Can an open tomb be safely copied?

Tags: mount, file-copy, tomb

I back up my tombs on Dropbox. My usual habit is to close them before pushing the changes with rclone. A couple of times I forget to close them first, but I haven't noticed any corruption. I've always been able to reopen them.

Is it safe to copy an open file container? Any difference with encrypted ones? On the surface I would think it's ok, but I acknowledge that I don't know everything.

Comment: Is this the tomb that you mean? https://www.dyne.org/software/tomb/

Comment: @Joseph Yes it is